# Scheduled tasks not running as expected

Tags: php, bash, cmd, task, windows-task-scheduler

I was trying to put a php file as a scheduled task on my windows server that runs daily. But it failed to run. 
The first time I created it I used the following command: 
schtasks /create /tn !NAMEOFTHETASK! /tr !URLofTheTask! /sc daily /st 08:00 
(*what I put at the URLofTheTask is the URL I use to manually run the php)
when I checked it the other day, the task status says the job could not be started.

Then I realized that putting the URL there is not going to work so I went to the task file and changed the text in it. It looks like the following:

[image]

instead of putting the URL in the argument I put in php.exe and the file path of the php file. 
now the job status says ready but it did not run also. 
But the php file runs with no problem when I do it manually. 
I was also not able to find the log file.

btw. I did all of this on vSphere so I only have the cmd not the scheduled task interface.

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by deleting the job and created a new one by the following command:

> Schtasks /create /tn [name of the task] /tr "php.exe [absolute path of the php file] arg1" /sc daily /st 08:00